# Download image php - Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using this php code in image.php file to merge a png image with text from facebook.

Can someone please help me to download this image from image.php to my server. I have tried alot of coding but failed.

code for image.php is:

```
<?php 

header("Content-Type: image/png"); 

include_once 'facebook.php';
include_once 'config.php'; //contains app id and secret key for fb app
include_once 'token.php'; // contains access token and initiates a valid session
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
));

$me = $facebook->api('/me');
$im = ImageCreateFrompng("certificate.png"); 

$black = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 0); 

$start_x = 35; 
$start_y = 230; 

Imagettftext($im, 20, 0, $start_x, $start_y, $black, 'ambient.ttf', $me['name']); 

Imagejpeg($im, '', 100); 

ImageDestroy($im); 
?>
```

Can someone please help me to download this image from image.php to my server. I have tried alot of coding but failed.

Comment: What is not working, what is the problem?

Comment: i think its clearly mentioned that i want to download the image from image.php file. donot give -ve votes to question if u hv some understanding problem

Comment: You are not describing *what exactly doesn't work*. That's kinda expected when looking for help with a problem.

Comment: i'm not able to download image from image.php thats the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save image in your server:

replace:

`Imagejpeg($im, '', 100);`

with this:

`Imagejpeg($im, '/path/to/your/dir/image.jpg', 100);`

Comment: hey Zulkhaery Basrul. Is thr any way so that i can send output to browser as well and at the same time save it to my server

Answer (score 2):

Check the [manual for imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php), the second parameter is the path to save the file to, so if you leave it empty, you will not be saving anything to your server.

The code you are using suggests outputting to the browser directly.

Comment: hey jeroen. Is thr any way so that i can send output to browser as well and at the same time save it to my server